# $z=0$ is a removal singularity of $f$. (T/F)

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

If $f(z)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$, then $z=0$ is a removal singularity of $f$. (T/F)

We know $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1$. Is the sam thought can be applied here?, Here $z=0$ is also branch point of $\sqrt z$ but $0$ is nt branch point of $f$. Help

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots$$So, if $w$ is *any* square root of $z$, then$$\sin w=w-w\frac z{3!}+w\frac{z^2}{5!}-\cdots$$and therefore$$\frac{\sin w}w=1-\frac z{3!}+\frac{z^2}{5!}-\cdots$$So, and although your question is not very precise, I would say that $0$ *is* a removable singularity of your function.

So, if you define$$f(z)=1-\frac z{3!}+\frac{z^2}{5!}-\cdots,$$then, no matter how you defined $\sqrt z$ (as long as it is a square root of $z$, of course), then $\frac{\sin\sqrt z}{\sqrt z}=f(z)$ and $f$ is a holomorphic function.

Comment: There's a subtle point that _is_ covered by what you wrote, but imo you might be more explicit about it: $f(z)$ _is_ in fact holomorphic (in particular "single-valued") for $z\ne0$. (From what the OP says about branch points it's not clear whether this fact was handed to him or it's part of what he needs to show...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've edited my answer. Thank you.